# Why are disqus comments not loading over https?

Tags: javascript, https, disqus

The disqus comments are loading here: http://www.oddprints.com/help
but not here: https://www.oddprints.com/help any ideas?

All resources appear to be secure (protocol relative urls) so I don't think it's that.

Comment: You can migrate all yours posts using this step by step which i found in the web: https://woorkup.com/migrate-disqus-comments-https/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It because disqus was treating the two urls as different and therefore loading different threads. If you want both http and https urls to have the same comments thread on it, you need to supply a canonical url in the disqus config. This is how I did it:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>
    /**
     *  https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables
     */
    var disqus_config = function () {
        this.page.url = "http://www.oddprints.com/help";
        //this.page.identifier = "oddprints"; // add a different id here if you want a fresh thread....
    };
    (function() {
        var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
        s.src = '//oddprints.disqus.com/embed.js';
        s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
        (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
    })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

Note that in the config I passed the `http` url as the canonical url and I've not set the `page.identifier`. I've done this so that it continues to serve up the comments I already had from back when it was just `http` and using an older version of the disqus snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Disqus comment are loaded but Disqus consider these two page as different.

Did you follow that : https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/542119-can-disqus-be-loaded-via-https- ?

Comment: Yeah, I followed that help page to do it.

Comment: Is there a way I can make disqus consider the two pages to be the same? Or migrate the comments across?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it set me thinking in the right direction. I've figured it out now (see my other answer). Cheers, Matt

Comment: You're welcome. As my answer was helpful maybe you can upvote it ?