# Disquss comments not loading via https

Tags: javascript, https, disqus

Yesterday we changed couple of URLs using the `Disqus` URL Mapper but now the comments somehow don't load via `https` but they do via `http`..

The code looks like this:

```
    var disqus_shortname = 'ourname';

    (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
```

The URLs we've changed:

```
http://domain.be/blog/2017/03/27/blog-name-old/, http://domain.be/blog/2017/03/27/blog-name/
https://domain.be/blog/2017/03/27/blog-name-old/, https://domain.be/blog/2017/03/27/blog-name/
```

I have read this, but this didn't work
[Why are disqus comments not loading over https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605638/why-are-disqus-comments-not-loading-over-https)

Comment: Have you looked at the browser's error console?

Comment: No errors are shown

Comment: Can you point to a live URL?

Comment: Hmm, Disqus seems to be loading ok for me on the https URL. Or do you just mean the literal *comments*? It's possible http:// and https:// will be treated as different resources by Disqus, so the comments are bound to the http:// one. I'm sure they have writeups on how to address that

Comment: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/912757-url-mapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour makes sense: a `http` URL is a different resource than a `https` URL and you can't expect comments for one of them to automatically show up in the other.

[Disqus' URL mapper tool](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/912757-url-mapper) should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense